# Python : importing different module with same name

Tags: python, python-import

I am working on a project that requires to have several modules with the same name. This is a representative extract of the architecture, with `__init__.py` files to show which folders are modules:

```
/path1
    /ProjectA
        __init__.py
        /src
            __init__.py
            /ctrl
                __init__.py
                somectrl.py
            ...
/path2
    /ProjectA
        __init__.py
        /src
            __init__.py
            someclass.py
```

And in my class `someclass.py`, I want to import `somectrl.py` like this :

```
from ProjectA.src.ctrl import somectrl
```

But the import fails: it tells me that there is no `ctrl` package. Seems like it just looks into `ProjectA` from `path2`, and completely ignores `ProjectA` from `path1` ! 
Both `path1` and `path2` are in my `PYTHONPATH`. So can't they both be reached?

Is there a clean way out of this nasty situation?

Comment: Except making "path1" and "path2" packages on their own I don't see much solution here.

Comment: *"I am working on a project that requires to have several modules with the same name"* - well there's your problem.

Comment: jonrsharpe - i am well aware that the situation itself is the problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use the imp module.

```
import imp
somectrl = imp.load_source("somectrl", "path1/ProjectA/src/ctrl/somectrl.py")
someclass = imp.load_source("someclass", "path2/ProjectA/src/someclass.py")
```